# Java Novice Saving and loading: Notepad

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea, notepad

Thank you for taking the time to read this, I'll get to the point. The problem I an having is that for some reason my practice Notepad is not doing what I want it to do. It works as you can write in it and such but the problem is that my save method only loads instead of save. Both of them load and I want one of them to save. I'm not sure if I made a mistake somewhere or maybe I did something wrong but here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Notepad extends JFrame {

    ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon("Water.bmp");

    private JFrame f = new JFrame("Notepad"); // Create Frame
    private JPanel pnlNorth = new JPanel(); //North Quadrant
    private JPanel pnlSouth = new JPanel(); //South Quadrant


    private JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar(); // Menu Bar
    private JMenu mnuFile = new JMenu("File"); // File Entry of Menu Bar
    private JMenuItem mnuItemQuit = new JMenuItem("Quit"); // Quit Sub item

    private JMenuItem mnuItemSave = new JMenuItem("Save");

    private JMenuItem mnuItemOpen = new JMenuItem("Open");

    private JMenu mnuHelp = new JMenu("Help"); //Help Menu Entry
    private JMenuItem mnuItemAbout = new JMenuItem("About"); //About Entry

    private JTextArea Ta = new JTextArea(10, 30);


    int fileSave;
    int fileOpen;
    JFileChooser sFile;
    JFileChooser oFile;


    public Notepad(){



        pnlSouth.add(Ta);

        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(pnlNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        f.getContentPane().add(pnlSouth,BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        //f.add(button);
f.addWindowListener(new ListenCloseWdw());

f.setJMenuBar(mb);

mnuItemQuit.addActionListener(new ListenMenuQuit());

mnuItemSave.addActionListener(new ListenMenuSave());

mnuItemOpen.addActionListener(new ListenMenuOpen());

//Build Menus
mnuFile.add(mnuItemQuit);//Create Quit Line
mnuFile.add(mnuItemSave);
mnuFile.add(mnuItemOpen);
mnuHelp.add(mnuItemAbout); //Create About Line
mb.add(mnuFile);        // Add Menu Items to form
mb.add(mnuHelp);




    }




    public class ListenCloseWdw extends WindowAdapter{
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }

    public class ListenMenuQuit implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }   
    }

    public class ListenMenuSave implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            sFile();

            if (fileSave == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                Ta.setText("");
                try {
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(sFile.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                    while(scan.hasNext())
                        Ta.append(scan.nextLine() + "\n");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }


        }
    }

    public class ListenMenuOpen implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            oFile();
            if (fileOpen == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                Ta.setText("");
                try {
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(oFile.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                    while(scan.hasNext())
                        Ta.append(scan.nextLine() + "\n");
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void sFile(){
        JFileChooser save = new JFileChooser();// Open up file chooser
        int option = save.showSaveDialog(this);
        fileSave= option;
        sFile = save;
    }

    public void oFile(){
        JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser();// Open up file chooser
        int option = open.showOpenDialog(this);
        fileOpen= option;
        oFile = open;

    }

    public void launchFrame(){
        //Display Frame
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack(); // Adjusting panel to components for Display
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Notepad gui = new Notepad();
        gui.launchFrame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a `Scanner` in the `ListenMenuSave` `ActionListener` for the `mnuItemSave` `JMenuItem` which is attempting to read the selected file in the save JFileChooser.

Use [JTextComponent#write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write%28java.io.Writer%29) to write the contents of the `JTextArea` instead.

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sFile.getSelectedFile());
ta.write(writer);
```

Remember to invoke `writer.close()` in a `finally` block to write any unwritten buffered data to disk.

Comment: glad someone knows how to use a finally block ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing almost the exact same thing in both listeners.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(oFile.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
while(scan.hasNext())
  Ta.append(scan.nextLine() + "\n");
```

You scan the given file and put it into your textfield. This is the behavior you want for load, but for save you are going to want to read the lines form the text field and write them off to a new file.

Comment: Oh thank you, I think I get it now. I was putting them wrong but thank you for your help.